# How create an async fetch function in React which returns something which I can use to build conditional logic

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, conditional-statements, fetch-api

I created this `fetch` function in my React app:

```
  const getStatus = () => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000`);

      const result = response.status;

      console.log(result);

      return result;
    };

    return fetchData();
  };
```

I want then use this function like:

```
getStatus() === 200 ? 'Do something' : 'Don't do something'
```

But now when I call function `getStatus()` it returns `undefined`?

How do I directly return something from `getStatus()` function, which I can use for e.g. a ternary operator?

Comment: You don't return anything from getStatus: `return fetchData()`

Comment: @DennisVash thanks. But now it returns Promise state pending `Promise {<pending>}`. How do I directly return something from `getStatus()` function?

Comment: When dealing with promises, you would need to await them, if you want response to be used in a component, put that promise in useEffect and on resolve of that promise, put response into the state.
This might be the only way to use it.

Comment: @LostStranger ok thanks. Are you able to create an example?

Answer (score 0):

With proper handling of Promises, it should be easier. Combine Promise handling with state to store response in.

Here's the sample code for the question.

Addition to this can also be managed for loading, so when `status` is null you can keep it as loading and the rest as you want to.

```js
import React from "react";

const AppStatus = () => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(null);
  const fetchStatus = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000`);
    return response.status;
  };

  useEffect(async () => {
    const response = await fetchStatus();
    setStatus(response);
  }, []);

  return <div>{status === 200 ? "Do something" : "Don't do something"}</div>;
};

export default AppStatus;
```

Answer (score 0):

the function "fetchData" is an async function, if you want to get value with async function, you have to use "await", eg: `const status = await fetchData()`.
so in you case, maybe modify it like below:

```
  // because inner getStatus you will execute 'fetchData' function
  // 'fetchData' should await it, so you have to change "getStatus" with async function
  const getStatus = async () => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000`);

      const result = response.status;

      console.log(result);

      return result;
    };

    const status = await fetchData();
    return status
  };
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem here is that when I want to use this function like: `getStatus() === 200 ? 'yes' : 'no'` it get `Promise {<pending>} `?

Comment: `const status = await getStatus(); status === 200 ? 'yes' : 'no'`